# Live IL Viewing of the typing code

Tags: reverse-engineering, il

Is there any tool that make it possible as we write CS Code (.Net Code) show us the equivalent IL Version of it,
Needed such a tool as learning purpose.

---

In one side we write sample code :
e.g: (Just as an example)
We write :

```
   if (base.ActiveMdiChild != null)
   {...
```

And in the other side it shows :

```
4        L_0009:    brtrue.s    9 -> ret 
5        L_000b:    ldarg.0
```

Comment: Could be via Reflection, JIT, Live Conversion, (Just may be without the need to be compiled) ...

Answer (score 1):

You could perhaps script a web tool similar to this using Roslyn:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/roslyn.aspx in a similar manner to https://compilify.net/ you would obviously need to compile before you can show il.

Perhaps you could ask for it as an option from the compilify folks.

Comment: Thanks I didn't study them, It'll took a time for me to visit and find how they could address my need.

Comment: I think it could be a different answer, though I put a +1 because had something new for me, I saw Roslyn before but never went through.